# MKR Vidor 4000 Verilog tutorial

Tags: arduino, fpga, verilog

I can't find any tutorial on how to write verilog on MKR Vidor 4000. If you have done it what software do you use to synthesize, simulate and create a bit stream to the board ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It has Cyclone10 FPGA from Intel. These FPGAs can be programmed with Quartus Software. Download it from Intel website. You can generate .bit files. I think, there are a lot of resource on the web. For example;
https://github.com/vidor-libraries/VidorFPGA

Comment: The Quartus equivalent of bit file is sof file.

Comment: Yes, also for nonvolatile it's pof file.